# Passing Data Descriptors to functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to pass a Data Descriptor Object to a function. Instead, the result of `__get__()` is passed.

The Data Descriptor classes: (code is sample code)

```
import time

class evenOdd():
    def __get__(self, obj, owner):
        return "even!" if (time.mktime(time.localtime()) % 2 == 0) else "odd!"


class testObject():
    a = evenOdd()
```

The following code prints "even! odd! even! odd! ...":

```
tester = testObject()

for i in range(10):
    print(tester.a, end=" ")
    time.sleep(1)
```

However, putting the for-loop in its own function generates either "even! even! even! even!..." or "odd! odd! odd! odd!...":

```
def printer(data):
    for i in range(10):
        print(data, end = " ")
        time.sleep(1)

tester = testObject()
printer(tester.a)
```

How can I pass the Data Descriptor Object to the function, rather than the result of `__get__()`?

EDIT: I've found a workaround based on jonrsharpes response that *sort of* does what I want it to:

```
def printer(data):
    for i in range(10):
        print(data(), end = " ")
        time.sleep(1)

tester = testObject()
printer(lambda: tester.a)
```

Unfortunately this means that `printer()` no longer works with Strings. If possible, I'd like `printer()` to accept both my Data Descriptor Objects as well as regular strings.

Comment: You can't, that's just not how Python works. The *value* is calculated to pass to the function; if you need to delay evaluation, you'd need to e.g. pass in a function.

Comment: You probably want `__repr__` or `__str__`

Comment: You totally _can_, by passing `testObject.a` instead of `tester.a`. You'd have to explicitly call `.__get__()` on it though-

Comment: Regarding your edit, you can just check if `isinstance(data, collections.abc.Callable)` to know if you have to call it or not.

Answer (score 0):

Using jonrsharpe and L3viathans responses, I've made the following code that does exactly what I need:

```
tester = testObject()

def printer(data):
    isCallable = isinstance(data, collections.abc.Callable)
    for _ in range(10):
        print(data() if isCallable else data, end = " ")
        time.sleep(1)

tester = testObject()
printer(lambda: tester.a)
print("")
printer("test")
```

This produces:

```
odd! even! odd! even! odd! even! odd! even! odd! even!
test test test test test test test test test test
```

Thanks for the help!